# Create terrain from vertices

Tags: uv, vertices

I'm trying to create terrain from a bunch of vertices I have exported from a real DEM map. I created a script that converts DEM data to a .obj file. But it creates just vertices, no edges and no faces.

I tried to connect them by hand, but it's seem like a crazy idea to connect 46110 vertices that way.

Is there a way to create terrain (plane) from all those vertices that I have?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could create a plane above it with the same number of subdivisions and then use a shrinkwrap modifier aiming at the vertices
[image]

[image]

Depending on the height difference of those vertices you might have to scale them down in the Z axis or manually move around the top plane so they don't shrinkwrap to the wrong vertex

Comment: Thanks! Worked out perfectly, exactly what I needed.